# Testing the contents in std::unordered_map without worrying about the order

Tags: c++, googlemock

I am looking to check whether the strings outputted match against the expected one without worrying about the order in which they are printed.

Here, `std::unordered_map` stores the `A` objects as values and since it's not ordered, it becomes tricky since the output can be either `foo\nbar\n` or `bar\nfoo\n`.

Any ways it could be tested in google mock?

```
class A
{
    std::string _name;

    public:
    A(std::string name) : _name(name) {}
    void foo() 
    {
        std::cout << _name << "\n";
    }
};

TEST(UnorderedMatch, A) 
{
    A a1{"foo"};
    A a2{"bar"};
    std::string expectedOut = "foo\nbar\n"; 
    std::unordered_map<int, A> m1 = { {1, a1}, {2, a2} };

    // test: foo()'s output matches expectedOut
    // verify output is "foo\nbar\n" without worrying about its order 
    for (auto e : m1)
    {
        e.second.foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about collecting the values into a sorted collection, and then checking the sorted output?

Comment: Either sort before outputting, or avoid checking the output and straight compare m1 with an unordered map containing the expected values.

Comment: Which part of this demonstration is the test and which part is the code being tested?

Comment: @Brian61354270 true but I wouldn't want to use `std::map` in the production just so I could test it since logically the items aren't supposed to be ordered

Comment: @user253751 the output to the stream by `e.second.foo()` is being tested against `expectedOut`

Comment: @xyf Then your problem is that the test is calling `e.second.foo()` in an unknown order. So have you considered simply changing the test? maybe you put them in a vector instead of an unordered_map? or you call m1[1].foo(); m1[2].foo(); ?

Comment: @xyf I think you've misunderstood @Brian61354270. He wasn't saying to switch to `std::map` in your production code. He was saying in the *test* copy over the items from your unordered collection to an ordered collection and *then* perform your test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that by verification you mean using gmock instruments, you could employ `UnorderedElementsAre` mentioned [here](https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#matching-containers). Otherwise refer to advice given in the comments.

Please note that using `UnorderedElementsAre` requires a comparison operator in `A`, so I've changed its definition a bit:

```
class A
{
    std::string _name;

public:
    auto operator<=>(A const&) const = default; // required by test
    A(std::string name) : _name(name) {}
    // ...
};
```

Example of `UnorderedElementsAre` usage:

```
TEST(UnorderedMatch, A)
{
    A a1{"foo"};
    A a2{"bar"};

    std::unordered_map<int, A> m1 = { {1, a1}, {2, a2}, };

    using namespace ::testing;
    using std::string_literals::operator""s;

    EXPECT_THAT(m1, UnorderedElementsAre( Pair(_, "bar"s), Pair(_, "foo"s) ));
}
```

Comment: can you also please provide a working example for `UnorderedElementsAre`?

Comment: Thanks though it fails: https://godbolt.org/z/ba7f8j4vh

Comment: @xyf indeed, it cannot compare instances of `A`. I've defined a defaulted `A::operator<=>` for the snippet I've posted.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying you just modified your snippet to account for this error?

Comment: No, I've modified the definition of `A`. I assume the type you're testing implements some sort of comparison.

Comment: Not sure if I followed. The snippet that's failing is yours so this isn't a compilable code

Comment: I've added clarifications to my post; I hope this edit helps.

Comment: Failed again: https://godbolt.org/z/f3n8qPM9b

Comment: At this point I can only suggest that you look at the error messages.

Comment: @xyf see my post.